# Running sudo on user-defined functions in fish

Tags: fish

```
» cat ~/.config/fish/config.fish
function take
    command mkdir $argv;and cd $argv
end

function check
  sudo dmesg -c>/dev/null;
  make clean; make;
  /usr/local/bin/kedr start $argv;
  sudo insmod "$argv.ko"; sudo rmmod $argv;
  /usr/local/bin/kedr stop
  dmesg;
end

function sudo
  if functions -q $argv[1]
    set argv fish -c "$argv"
  end
  command sudo $argv
end
```

While running I get this error:

```
» sudo check "simple-no-macro"
fish: Unknown command 'check simple-no-macro'
fish:
check simple-no-macro
^
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked this on GitHub as well, so here's [my answer from there](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4710#issuecomment-363653586):

The problem here is that the function you've defined isn't present in the new instance of fish you start.

You'd be better off defining the `check` function in a file saved in `~/.config/fish/functions/check.fish`, which will then let the function work across instances.

Side note: bash does let you export functions across instances using environment variables, but both zsh and ksh use a similar method to fish - see [Propagating shell functions from *Unix Power Tools*](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch29_13.htm).